# Unable to find kafka-ignite connector files in ApacheIgnite 2.10.0 binary release

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite, gridgain

I have downloaded apache ignite 2.10.0 binary release. I am unable find Kafka-ignite folder which should be part of libs/optional in package which contains ignite sink connector jars and required instruction. But same is present in earlier versions. How can I use connector?
Please suggest.

Comment: You might get a more direct answer from the mailing list - https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html

Comment: Hi, take a look to answer in this thread
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rf9e35e0c87acf6436c1abfde28df09c7c4e93c5891df9775833914cd%40%3Cuser.ignite.apache.org%3E